Cannot find symbol with Lombok
Basically I'm trying to create an API using Spring Boot, however I'm with some problems with lombok annotations I guess.
This is my domain (I can use @Data, but it shows the same error):
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    public UUID id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String email;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 8)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public UserRoles role;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Timestamp createdAt;
}

This is my service:
@Service
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public User createUser(UserDto dto) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(dto.name());
        user.setEmail(dto.email());
        user.setPassword(dto.password());

        this.userRepository.save(user);

        return user;
    }
}

In my pom.xml I have the following related with lombok:
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
<configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

And the error that I'm getting is related with the boilerplate code I think.
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method setName(java.lang.String)
location: variable user of type com.example.restproject.domain.user.User

I have the annotation processing in the settings enabled.

Why do you exclude lombok?

@talexmovedtoCodidact I didn't change pom.xml, I don't know xD but it doesn't work anyway if I remove it.

Why your fields are public?

yeah, all of them are public

How has this error been shown, when you run mvn command or shown by IDE?
If IDE, which IDE are you using?

Try updating your pom.xml to:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>your Project name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   
    <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <version>1.18.28</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependecny>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
             <source>17</source>
             <target>17</target>
             <annotationsProcessorPaths>
                 <path>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifact>
                    <version>1.18.28</version>
                 </path>
             </annoatationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
</project>

After updating your pom.xml, clean-install your maven project using the comman:
mvn clean install

If this does not resolve then, enable the annotation processing in your IDE.
For intelliJ, you can search:
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors.

I've done all of that and still does not compile.

Try Settings -> Build, Execution, Development -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> Processor Path -> search and insert your path to lombok


I've done that and still does not work.
